# Elasticsearch starts and stops immediately

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to start Elasticsearch process from Services. It starts, then stops immediately.

Laptop with Windows 10. 
I've tried different versions, I've tried .msi and installing from zip. 
Now I'm stuck with elasticsearch-6.8.0.
System variable JAVA_HOME added. ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre1.8.0_211").

I don't see anything in logs:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (25.211-b12) for windows-x86 JRE (1.8.0_211-b12), built on Apr  1 2019 20:53:53 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 10.0 (VS2010)
Memory: 4k page, physical 6590616k(3782852k free), swap 7639192k(4460440k free)
CommandLine flags: -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:ErrorFile=logs/hs_err_pid%p.log -XX:GCLogFileSize=67108864 -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath=data -XX:InitialHeapSize=2147483648 -XX:MaxHeapSize=2147483648 -XX:MaxNewSize=268435456 -XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=6 -XX:NewSize=268435456 -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=32 -XX:OldPLABSize=16 -XX:OldSize=536870912 -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow -XX:+PrintGC -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps -XX:+PrintTenuringDistribution -XX:ThreadStackSize=1024 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:-UseLargePagesIndividualAllocation -XX:+UseParNewGC
```

Answer (score 0):

It could be java heap issue. Can you try reducing max and min heap value in elasticsearch\config\jvm.options

Reduce below value
-Xms2g
-Xmx2g

to 
-Xms1g
-Xmx1g

or lower

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

I already had 1Gb of min/max Java heap. So this didnt work for me.
I just unistalled Java, and reinstalled JDK. 
Still have no idea what was the reason or crashing but now it works.

Thank you